# What does the cef function do in this matlab code?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am currently looking at Henning Voss's implementation of the ACE algorithm in Matlab [Link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39766-alternating-conditional-expectation-algorithm--ace-)

I see uses of a `cef()` function but do not know what it means...

Excerpt from the program:

```
phi(d,:)=cef(phi(1,:)-sum0,ind(d,:),ranks(d,:),wl,ll);

function r=cef(y,ind,ranks,wl,ll)
cey=win(y(ind),wl,ll);
r=cey(ranks);

function r=win(y,wl,ll)
% wl=0,1,2...
r=conv(y,ones(2*wl+1,1));
r=r(wl+1:ll+wl)/(2*wl+1);
r(1:wl)=r(wl+1); r(ll-wl+1:ll)=r(ll-wl);
```

Where d is an int, phi is a m x n matrix, sum0 is a number, ind is a m x n matrix, ranks is a m x n matrix, wl is the "width of the smoothing kernel", and ll is the number of data points.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: cef() is a subroutine supplied with the ACE code at that link, not a standard Matlab function. Is your question what the subroutines are doing in that code?

Comment: yeah sorry I should have been more specific...I don't really understand matlab that well so could you guide me through what the cef, win, and whatever other combination of functions there are do?

Comment: I'd need to look up the author's paper (supplied in the code comments) to understand what they are doing. Did you do that - i.e do your understand the algorithm and the issue is just the Matlab implementation?

Comment: I implemented my own algorithm in python based on the paper (and got different results)...but this implementation looks completely different (e.g. I don't see how they calculated the conditional expected value without finding the empirical probability matrices and I don't see any normalization steps either.